# How to set different fill colour for scale guide in geom_jitter?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I want to create a plot where the geom_points (or jitters) are filled after a given value, but their line color is white.

However, setting colour to white makes it so the legend shows invisible points, and is rather useless. How can I force the legend to display black points with the correct size, but the actual plot has different colour and fill?

An example of what I have gotten to work:

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(disp, mpg, size = cyl, fill = mpg)) +
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.8, pch = 21) +
  scale_size_continuous(trans = 'log10') +
  scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

How can i set `color = 'white'` inside `geom_jitter`, without creating a useless legend?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override specific aesthetics in the legend of a scale by using `guide_legend(override.aes = list(...))`. Example below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg, size = cyl, fill = mpg)) +
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.8, pch = 21, colour = "white") +
  scale_size_continuous(
    trans = 'log10',
    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "black"))
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: is there an opinion how these 2 legends would be forced to display `fill` and `size` at the same time?

Comment: Brilliant, this was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Comment: @bird you can only merge legends if they have the same properties (titles, breaks, labels, etc.). The easiest way to do this is to set the aesthetics to the same column, i.e. `aes(size = var, fill = var)`. Because the fill here is continuous, you should then set the guide to a legend instead of the default colourbar.